# Local facebook testing

Tags: facebook, testing, laravel, facebook-php-sdk

I cannot get local facebook testing working.

I have already named my app in `/etc/hosts` to `superapp.app` and I changed the paths from localhost to superapp.app

I am using Hybridauth to authenticate users. When I Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id. After the app window opened and I was asked to submit my profile, it happens when it redirects!

[image]

I guess it has to do with the App settings of Facebook.

In base_facebook.php I have:

```
 /**
   * Default options for curl.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 50,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.2',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
  );



 /**
   * Indicates if we trust HTTP_X_FORWARDED_* headers.
   *
   * @var boolean
   */
  protected $trustForwarded = true;

  /**
   * Indicates if signed_request is allowed in query parameters.
   *
   * @var boolean
   */
  protected $allowSignedRequest = false;



<?php
return array(
"base_url" => "http://localhost:8000/fbauth/auth",
"providers" => array (
"Facebook" => array (
"enabled" => TRUE,
"keys" => array ("id" => "787714197957925", "secret" =>
"mysecret"),
"scope" => "email",
"trustForwarded" => true,
)
)
);



oauth.php

<?php
return array(
"base_url" => "http://localhost:8000/oauth/auth",
"providers" => array (
"Facebook" => array (
"enabled" => TRUE,
"keys" => array ("id" => "787714197957925", "secret"
=> "mysecret"),
"scope" => "email",
),
)
);
```

I only have the standard user model.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function($table)
{
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('email');
$table->string('password', 64);
$table->string('name');
$table->boolean('admin');
$table->timestamps();
});
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }

}
```

My routes.php

```
Route::get('facebook', function()
{
return "<a href='fbauth'>Login with Facebook</a>";
});

Route::get('fbauth/{auth?}', function($auth = NULL)
{
        if ($auth == 'auth') {
        try {
            Hybrid_Endpoint::process();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return Redirect::to('fbauth');
        }
        return;
    }
    try {
        $oauth = new Hybrid_Auth(app_path()
    . '/config/fb_auth.php');
        $provider = $oauth->authenticate('Facebook');
        $profile = $provider->getUserProfile();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo 'Welcome ' . $profile->firstName . ' '
        . $profile->lastName . '
';
    echo 'Your email: ' . $profile->email . '
';
    dd($profile);
});
```

My app settings:

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong in local facebook testing? I have reset the app secret and I am sure that the error is due to the facebook app testing settings. To make it work, I will have to create the SSL on my local computer. How do I do this? I have also added my public IP to the server whitelist.

Comment: Add some debug code and find out what the User ID actually is. The SDK you're using may not work with the recent Graph API changes. Update your answer with the FB ID the SDK gets from Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have the solution: It will NOT work without using Homestead for Laravel, you may no longer disable SSL.

You need to install a virtual machine.